# bootstrap col-md-4 and col-xs-6 not compatible

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, col

I have 3 columns for medium screens (col-md-4).
and I use also col-xs-6 to have 2 columns for mobile devices

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">CONTENT</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">CONTENT</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">CONTENT</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">CONTENT</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">CONTENT</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">CONTENT</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the problem is the out put in mobile.

**OUTPUT - col-md-4 and col-xs-6**

[col-xs-6] [col-xs-6]

[col-xs-6]

[col-xs-6] [col-xs-6]

[col-xs-6]

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

[col-xs-6] [col-xs-6]

[col-xs-6][col-xs-6]

[col-xs-6][col-xs-6]

is there a way to fix that.

thanks

**sample work**

[Link](http://foamcutters.net/clicker-press-parts.php)

Comment: Then you should put 2 `col-xs-6` in 1 row.

Comment: If I do that, what will happen to col-md-4?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\`col-xs-\*\` not working in Bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41794746/col-xs-not-working-in-bootstrap-4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">CONTENT</div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">CONTENT</div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">CONTENT</div>    
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">CONTENT</div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">CONTENT</div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">CONTENT</div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

in bootstrap 4 and above you can use:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-6">CONTENT</div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-6">CONTENT</div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-6">CONTENT</div>    
            <div class="col-md-4 col-6">CONTENT</div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-6">CONTENT</div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-6">CONTENT</div>
        </div>
 </div>
```